# How to add parameters to ServeHTTP?

Tags: http, go, routes

I would like to [add a middleware to Gorilla](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#middleware) that "enriches" the call with extra parameters:

```
// a middleware that adds a parameter "message"
func authCheck(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        message := "hello"
        log.Info().Msgf("adding message %v", message)
        // the core of my question is here: how to pass "message" further
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

I would like to add `message` as a parameter that could be ultimately used in a route:

```
main() {
    // (...)
    r.HandleFunc("/check", check).Methods(http.MethodGet)
    // (...)
    r.Use(authCheck)
    // (...)
}

func check(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // I would like to use "message" here, having it passed somehow to the function
    w.Write([]byte(message))
}
```

Is such an approach possible in Go?

Comment: it seems a job for `*http.Request.Context`. Inside `authCheck` you re-set the request context with request-scoped values e.g. `req = req.WithContext(context.WithValue(req.Context(), key, message))`. As for what `key` is, the standard advice about interface comparisons apply. tl;dr use an unexported struct

Comment: @blackgreen No need an unexported _struct_ for the key type, just an _unexported_ type, e.g. `type myKeyType int` will suffice. If you want printing contexts (and values in it) to be more informative, `type myKeyType string` is a better choice, but using a struct is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments and pointers, I managed to pass the variable. For reference:

```
type httpContextStruct struct {
    user  string
    wazaa string
}

var httpContext httpContextStruct

func authCheck(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        httpContext = httpContextStruct{}
        r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(
            r.Context(),
            httpContext,
            httpContextStruct{
                user:  "thisisme",
                wazaa: "aaa",
            },
        ))
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func check(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    myc := r.Context().Value(httpContext).(httpContextStruct)
    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("user: %v", myc.user)))
}

// output
// user: thisisme
```